# ios Infinite TimeLine(Trackbar) UIScrollView TRSDialScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, infinite-scroll

i try to make Time Trackbar timeline.
so, I searched this project

https://github.com/kevinkirkup/TRSDialScrollView

i build it and test.

but if i input very big number, this app charges very big memory.
(In TRSDialView)

For example,
[_dialView setDialRangeFrom:0 to:10000];

I have known that UIScrollView managed memory about displayed area
so, not displayed area is cliped.

i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: hi @poten1129 did you guys able to resolve the bigger range problem? i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I download this example and set the range same as yours. I found that the memory is consumed by TRSDialView not TRSDialScrollView. If you enter a big value in **to**, it will create a big TRSDialView embedded in TRSDialScrollView. And this **BIG** TRSDialView will consume a lot of memory.

You can use the **UIScrollViewDelegate** methods. In first, you set small range in viewDidLoad like this:

```
[_dialView setDialRangeFrom:0 to:50];
```

Then you can write code in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating or scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: like this:

```
NSInteger value = self.dialView.currentValue;

[_dialView setDialRangeFrom:value-50 to:value+50];

_dialView.currentValue = value;
```

This will make new range with small View after ending scrolling. But it might not look well.

Comment: Yeah you are right.. i mistake 
i must modify it.
TRSDialView  consumes a lot of memory
i want to decrease TRSDialView even though i set big range.
what can i do..

Comment: Hi @poten1129, I got an idea to work around memory problem. I edit my answer. But it is not very well, so you still need to adjust your code if you want.

Comment: hi @CloudTuan  did you guys able to resolve the bigger range problem? i am also facing the same issue.